# is Vb/a and Vba not the same thing?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

[image: question]

I wanted to ask isn't Vba and Vb/a the same thing?

Comment: Letters  and symbols can represent things. Sometimes different ones represent the same things, but this case is unlikely in this context- assuming the question is multiple choice with one answer.  You may need to provide context to support why you think different symbols represent the same thing.